# Talend : how to change context variables for all jobs?

Tags: talend

I am now working on Talend Open Studio. I have many jobs.

I need to modify the content of my unique context repository, for instance, to add a new context variable. thus, i wish to spread this new context variable in all the jobs I have.

For now, I had to open each job and manually to add manually the context variable I want to spread into the jobs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to directly spread a context variable in all my jobs from the context repository I have modified ?

Comment: Can you share your code and research work first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug even I have come across. On some occasions, just updating and saving the context groups propagates the updates across all the jobs using that context group. At some other times, it does not.

As per the link below, Shong from Talend team says that this is supposed to be manual as not all context variables are needed in all jobs. However, I personally feel, this should be the other way round. Whatever is not needed should be manually removed, else all updates should be reflected in all jobs.

https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=19199